# How to override a method and keep its original code in Dart / Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, class, methods, overriding

i'd like to override the method "dispose" by adding a function in it (let's imagine `print()`), but i'd like to keep its original purpose because otherwise it sometimes throws parent stability errors. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `super` to run inherited parent class method:

```
class A {
  a() {
    print("a");
   }
 }

class B extends A {
  @override
  a() {
    super.a();
    print("b");
   }
 }
```

now running `B().a()`:

```
 B().a();

 // output:
 a
 b
```